# С помощью какого метода можно получить файл из Интернета?

Tags: python, request

С помощью какого метода можно получить файл из Интернета?

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests # импорт библиотеки
req = requests.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions') # делаем запрос используя метод GET
with open('ru-stackoverflow-questions.html', 'wb') as file: # открытие файла
    file.write(req.content) # запись в файл
print('Файл успешно записан')
```